# DataBinding filter and date comparison

Tags: c#, data-binding, dataset

I have a dataset with a column containing date in "DAY-MONTH-YEAR TIME" format. That dataset is bound to datagridview with "dataBinding" object. Dataset is not typed, it's not connected to any database, it's filled "on the fly" with data from user input.
I also have two datetime pickers - one for selecting minimum date, another for selecting maximum date for results. When user select some "minimum" date from datetime picker, results in datagridview should be filtered according to selection. I know how to use "dataBinding.Filter" but how to filter when i need to select only rows whose "Date" column falls between "dataTimePickerMin" and "dateTimePickerMax"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the dates with DateTime.Parse and type the column as DateTime:

```
dataBinding.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("someDate", typeof(DateTime)));
```

then you can use > and <

Comment: sorry, but how to "type the column as DateTime"? :) something like "Date as DateTime"?

Comment: You need to do this when you declare your DataTable (I'm assuming that your "dataBinding" object is a DataTable) - see my edit.